# Animate element keeps pushing other elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I am having this issue where my social media icons animation keeps pushing other elements. I tried applying padding but it kept subtracting the the icons.

I've tried box-sizing: border-box, I've tired applying the padding in the jQuery code as well.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".smedia").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).animate({height:'60px',width:'60px'});
    $(this).mouseout(function(){
      $(this).animate({height:'50px',width:'50px'}); 
    });
  });
});
```

It keeps pushing other elements above and below when I mouse over them. They start out at 50px and grow to 60px, and back to 50px.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are changing the actual size of the elements - which pushes the other elements around - as they need to follow the flow of the document.

You could achieve this effect with CSS only, and not cause the surrounding element to be affected:

```
.smedia {
    position: relative;
    transform: scale(1);
    transition: transform .5s;
}

.smedia:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```